# Map rotated 90 degrees?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a class `Grid`, which manages all map functions. The issue is, the pacman map is rotated by 90 degrees anticlockwise.

How it looks

[image: The issue]

How it should look

[image: The 'fixed' version]

I got the 'fixed' version by swapping out `grid[x][y]` to be `grid[y][x]` inside `isWall()` (an untidy, incorrect method)

Here is the whole code for the `Grid` class;

```
package com.jackwilsdon.pacman.game;

import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;

public class Grid {
    public static final int BLOCK_SIZE = 20;

    public int[][] grid = null;

    public Grid()
    {
        grid = new int[][]  {   {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
                                {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
                                {0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0},
                                {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
                                {0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0},
                                {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0},
                                {0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0},
                                {0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0},
                                {0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0},
                                {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
                                {0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0},
                                {0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0},
                                {0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0},
                                {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
                                {0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0},
                                {0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0},
                                {0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0},
                                {0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0},
                                {0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0},
                                {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
                                {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0}     };
    }

    public boolean isWall(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x >= 0 && x < grid.length && y >= 0 && y < grid[0].length)
        {
            return grid[y][x] == 1;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        for (int cX = 0; cX < grid.length; cX++)
        {
            for (int cY = 0; cY < grid[cX].length; cY++)
            {
                if (this.isWall(cX, cY))
                {
                    g.fillRect(cX*Grid.BLOCK_SIZE, cY*Grid.BLOCK_SIZE, Grid.BLOCK_SIZE, Grid.BLOCK_SIZE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Have I made a silly mistake in my code?

I don't want to switch x and y, as that is no longer the proper format for the 2d array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see with your code is that the bounds check is incorrect. In other words, this piece of code:

```
if (x >= 0 && x < grid.length && y >= 0 && y < grid[0].length)
{
    return grid[y][x] == 1;
}
```

should actually be

```
if (x >= 0 && x < grid[0].length && y >= 0 && y < grid.length)
{
    return grid[y][x] == 1;
}
```

Your current code works only because the dimensions are equal (the map is square).

You have the same error in `draw` function. In other words, it should be

```
for (int cY = 0; cY < grid.length; cY++)
{
    for (int cX = 0; cX < grid[cY].length; cX++)
    {
        if (this.isWall(cX, cY))
        {
            g.fillRect(cX*Grid.BLOCK_SIZE, cY*Grid.BLOCK_SIZE, Grid.BLOCK_SIZE, Grid.BLOCK_SIZE);
        }
    }
}
```

In any case, `grid[y][x]` is correct and not `grid[x][y]` because `grid[i]` refers to the *row* at index `i` of the 2D array, not column.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a symptom of the fact that `grid[i][j]` refers to the `j`th element in the `i`th sub-array, which is actually the position at the `j`th column and the `i`th row in your formatted grid.

Since you want `x` to represent the column and `y` to represent the row, `grid[y][x]` is the correct way to access a position in your array.